# USPS send issue in return as Address Not Found

Tags: c#, asp.net, ups, usps

I am passing to address and from address to USPS but receiving issue as **"Address Not Found."**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Error><Number>-2147219401</Number>
 <Source>Validation:ValidateAMSAddress</Source><Description>Address Not Found.</Description><HelpFile/><HelpContext/></Error>
```

passing value as

```
https://secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=DeliveryConfirmationV3&XML=<DeliveryConfirmationV3.0Request USERID="XXXXXXXXX" PASSWORD="XXXXXXXX"><Option>1</Option><ImageParameters></ImageParameters><FromName>Mitesh Jain</FromName><FromFirm></FromFirm><FromAddress1>Ahmedabad</FromAddress1><FromAddress2>Ahmedabad</FromAddress2><FromCity>a</FromCity><FromState>CO</FromState><FromZip5>43209</FromZip5><FromZip4></FromZip4><ToName>test name</ToName><ToFirm></ToFirm><ToAddress1>test address 1</ToAddress1><ToAddress2>test address 2</ToAddress2><ToCity>TestCity</ToCity><ToState>Co</ToState><ToZip5>43209</ToZip5><ToZip4></ToZip4><WeightInOunces>0</WeightInOunces><ServiceType>Priority</ServiceType><POZipCode></POZipCode><ImageType>PDF</ImageType><LabelDate></LabelDate><CustomerRefNo></CustomerRefNo><AddressServiceRequested>False</AddressServiceRequested><SenderName></SenderName><SenderEMail></SenderEMail><RecipientName></RecipientName><RecipientEMail></RecipientEMail></DeliveryConfirmationV3.0Request>
```

I don't know what is the issue as I am using this 1st time

Comment: It sounds like _the address wasn't found_ on their end.  Are you sure what you are passing **is a valid address**?

Comment: @maccettura I am passing address as test address 1...Is this wrong for testing purpose?

Comment: If you are passing a made up address for testing, then you have to understand why the API is telling you the address is not found right?

Comment: If you want to test the functionality you will need to provide it with valid addresses that exist.  They don't have to be addresses that matter to you in any way, only that they are **real, existing addresses**.

Comment: You are sending a an address that doesn't exist and the API is telling you the address is not found. Seems to be working fine to me.

Comment: @maccettura  thanks, after passing valid message it is working fine for me, can u say me what is the exact length limit for passing address 1/ address2 / city / email id ?

Comment: I don't know personally, never used the API. You can read through [the docs](https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/address-information-api.htm#_Toc410982981) though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was not passing valid address issue was coming on passing valid addresses all set well.
Also review this link:

https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/address-information-api.htm#_Toc410982981

Thanks to @maccettura for giving me this link